# Python - Why call methods during __init__()

Tags: python, qt

I've been looking at some tutorials for some PyQt4 stuff and It Is Good, but I don't quite understand why the syntax when creating an object is such:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        #code to set up instance variables and show() the window
```

What is gained exactly from doing it in this way, and not just eliminating the `self.initUI()` call entirely and just putting any code that sets attributes in the `__init__()` after the `super` is called?

Comment: Most likely for readability and reuse.

Comment: In many languages this is done for code reuse between multiple constructors. It can also be useful if you want to reinitialize the object at some point.

Comment: Or override in a subclass which doesn't call `initUI`, or calls it differently.

Comment: Indeed, why call methods at all.  My apologies for asking a question to which you might know the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes code is separated into functions for readability purposes.

If your object initialization requires three steps, then logically it would make sense to break it into three functions. The names of those functions could describe which portion of the initialization they handle.

Another reason you might see an "init" function called from the true `__init__` is if that function restores the object to a fresh state; in that case, you might want to call the "clean" function from outside `__init__` in, for example, an object pool.

You've also hinted at a third reason for the reuse in your own question: if a subclass needs to change the order in which portions of the initialization happen (or omit/replace some portions entirely!) this is not possible with a monolithic `__init__` but easy if it's split into separate parts.

A fourth and final reason is for profiling. If you track function entries/exists and timings, separate functions gives you finer granularity in the timing metrics.

Regardless, how you code is up to you - but the approach you question here *does* have merits.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer.  Now that it's explained to me, of course it makes all the sense in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps so that initUI can be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Only one reason I know of, the same as most languages -- usability.  The core of Object Oriented programming, is the ability to re-use things -- be they classes, methods or variables.  By separating our different methods/functions, we can call them later on.  Whether you ever *will* call them later...that's debatable.  I think it comes down to good programming practice.